# EntityFramework is trying to fetch non-existing column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

EntityFramework is trying to fetch non-existing column and foreign key attribute doesn't help.

In my case, I have two tables with single to multiple relationships:

```
  T_Blog
- Id
- FeaturedPost

  T_Post
- Id
- BlogId
```

and I defined entity data model

```
public class T_Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? FeaturedPostId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("FeaturedPostId")]
    public virtual T_Post FeaturedPost {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<T_Post> Posts {get;set;}
}

public class T_Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public int BlogId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
    public T_Blog Blog {get;set;}
}
```

And having this metadata defined EF is trying to fetch `T_Blog_Id` column everytime I'm trying to execute db.T_Post.Where(...).ToList();

I got it that as long as my T_Blog has two references to T_Post, then EF is trying to fetch both Ids.

ps: yeah, I know this type of data model is not optimal but this type of denormalization is needed in my case (at least as of now).

How to properly define the second relationship so EF knows what to fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the FluentAPI instead of annotations to avoid that kind of mapping fails.

Here is a sample for your model

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext()
        : base( "name=BlogContext" )
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );

        var blog = modelBuilder.Entity<T_Blog>();

        blog.HasKey( e => e.Id );
        blog.HasOptional( e => e.FeaturedPost )
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.FeaturedPostId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

        var post = modelBuilder.Entity<T_Post>();

        post.HasKey( e => e.Id );
        post.HasRequired( e => e.Blog )
            .WithMany( e => e.Posts )
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.BlogId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( true );
    }

    public virtual DbSet<T_Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<T_Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class T_Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<T_Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public int? FeaturedPostId { get; set; }
    public virtual T_Post FeaturedPost { get; set; }
}

public class T_Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual T_Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

and the autogenerated migration

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.T_Blog",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FeaturedPostId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.T_Post", t => t.FeaturedPostId)
            .Index(t => t.FeaturedPostId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.T_Post",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    BlogId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.T_Blog", t => t.BlogId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.BlogId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.T_Blog", "FeaturedPostId", "dbo.T_Post");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.T_Post", "BlogId", "dbo.T_Blog");
        DropIndex("dbo.T_Post", new[] { "BlogId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.T_Blog", new[] { "FeaturedPostId" });
        DropTable("dbo.T_Post");
        DropTable("dbo.T_Blog");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fluent API is great to avoid this kind of confusion. I will give it a shot. As of now, Attributes were more convenient as long as required less code write and (which is even more important) less to refactor when something is changed.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit after I lost an hour in my researches I found the answer. If EF is unable to define the mapping you should define not only the `ForeignKey` but also the `InverseProperty`

```
public class T_Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? FeaturedPostId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("FeaturedPostId")]
    public virtual T_Post FeaturedPost {get;set;}
    [InverseProperty("Blog")]
    public virtual ICollection<T_Post> Posts {get;set;}
}
```

Found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx)